# Spring Cache: enable/disable caching

Tags: xml, spring, caching, ehcache

I'm developing a REST API with Spring. I'm caching data with EHCache (with Spring Cache). My caches are configured in `ehcache.xml` file and the CacheManager is configured in `applicationContext.xml` file. Moreover, I use `@Cacheable` to denote which data must be cached.

It works properly, but now I want to enable/disable this caching by reading an external property of a properties file. Like `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in `applicationContext.xml`.

Is there any way to do that without filtering (with Maven) `ehcache.xml`, or create/access caches programatically (I want still using xml-based configuration and annotations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought of using Spring profiles?

Basically you can separate your configurations behavior in different profiles (dev, test, staging, prod, and what ever you want), and configure your beans, so that they would be created depending on active profile (with -Dspring.profiles.active). This feature was introduced long time ago in Spring 3.1, even before Caching, so I believe you already have it in your current Spring version.

You can read more:

- http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles
- http://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles